# Clustsig with modified method.distance

Tags: correlation, cluster-analysis

I am attempting to perform a Simprof test using a Pearson correlation as a distance method. I am aware that it is designed for the typical distance methods such as euclidean or bray curtis, but it supposedly allows any function that returns a dist object.

My issue lies with the creation of that function. My original data exists as a set of 35 rows and 2146 columns. I wish to correlate the columns. Below is a small subset of that data (lines 78-82).

I need a function that takes the absolute value of the Pearson correlation coefficient metric to be used as the method.distance function. I can calculate those individually, as seen in lines 84-86, but I have no idea how to make a single function that contains all of that. My attempt is on lines 89-91, but I know that as.dist needs the matrix of correlation coefficients, which you can only get from CorrelationSmall$r. I'm assuming it needs to be nested, but I'm at a loss. I apologize if I'm am asking something ridiculous. I have combed the forums and don't know who else to ask. Many thanks!

```
library(clustsig)
library(Hmisc)

NetworkAnalysisSmall <- read_csv("C:/Users/WilhelmLab/Desktop/Lena/NetworkAnalysisSmall.csv")
NetworkAnalysisSmallMatrix<-as.matrix(NetworkAnalysisSmall)
#subset of NetworkAnalysisSmall

a<-c(0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000001505,0.0000000000685,0.0000000009909,0.0000000001543,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000)
b<-c(0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000002228,0.0000000000000,0.0000000001375,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000)
c<-c(0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000546,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000002293,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000540,0.0000000002085,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000)

subset<-data.frame(a,b,c)

CorrelationSmall<-rcorr(as.matrix(NetworkAnalysisSmall),type=c("pearson"))
CCsmall<-CorrelationSmall$r
CCsmallAbs<-abs(CCsmall)


dist3 = function(x) {
      as.dist(rcorr(as.matrix(x),type=c("pearson")))
    }


 NetworkSimprof<-simprof(NetworkAnalysisSmall,num.expected=1000,num.simulated=1000,method.cluster=c("ward"),method.distance=c("dist3"),method.transform=c("log"),alpha=0.05,sample.orientation="column")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please read https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/top-k-list-of-reasons-to-close-a-question-immediately, https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, and take action accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have caused offense.  Im very much at a loss. I thought I had done everything right. I provided a visual of the raw data, showed the work I had done, searched every forum in attempt to solve this problem myself, etc. Please tell me what else to do? I posted this as a last resort.

Comment: No offense caused. In short, please clean up the first picture by converting it to a table. And please type out the code in `code mode`. See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: I did my best. Is this better?